# How to Redirect to Other URLs in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

requests.py

```
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        print(request)

        form_data = request.form
        print(form_data)

        self.set_instance()
        print(self.instance)

        for es in self.instance.epoxy_systems:
            for response in es.responses:
                print(response.id)

                res_id = str(response.id)

                value = form_data.get(res_id)
                # print(value)

                actual_value = form_data.get(res_id + '_actual')
                # print(actual_value)

                comments = form_data.get(res_id + '_comments')

                question = response.epoxy_system_question.question

                question_has_options = question.options
                if question_has_options:
                    # form_value = form_data.getlist(str(response.id))
                    value = form_data.getlist(res_id, None)
                    actual_value = form_data.getlist(res_id + '_actual', None)
                else:
                    # form_value = form_data.get(str(response.id), None)
                    value = form_data.get(res_id, None)
                    actual_value = form_data.get(res_id + '_actual', None)

                if isinstance(value, list):
                    selected_options = {so.option_id: so for so in response.selected_options}
                    selected_options_actual = {so.option_id: so for so in response.selected_options_actual}

                    for so in selected_options.values():
                        if so.option_id not in value:
                            so.hard_delete()
                    for v in value:
                        so = selected_options.get(v)
                        if not so:
                            RFQResponseSelectedOptions(
                                response_id=response.id,
                                option_id=v,
                            ).create()

                    for so in selected_options_actual.values():
                        if so.option_id not in value:
                            so.hard_delete()
                    for v in actual_value:
                        so = selected_options_actual.get(v)
                        if not so:
                            RFQResponseSelectedOptionsActual(
                                response_id=response.id,
                                option_id=v,
                            ).create()

                else:
                    response.value = value if value else None
                    response.actual_value = actual_value if actual_value else None

                response.comments = comments if comments else None
                response.update()
        return redirect(request.referrer)
```

form_response.html

```
{% extends '_base/base.html' %}
{% from 'bootstrap5/form.html' import render_form, render_field %}
{% from "macros/header.html" import page_header %}
{% from "macros/buttons.html" import generate_button_link, generate_button_form, generate_detail_button_form %}


{% block content %}

    {{ page_header(
title=page_title,
title_icon=page_title_icon,
actions=page_actions
) }}


    <form method="post" name="form" id="form">

        <div class="py-3">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion-a">

                <!-- <div class="card "> -->
                <!-- <div class="card-body"> -->
                {#
      {{ render_form(form, id='form', extra_classes="form-control-sm") }}
      #}

                {% for es in es_forms %}
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-bs-target="#panel-{{ es.epoxy_system.id }}"
                                    aria-controls="panel-{{ es.epoxy_system.id }}">
                                {{ es.epoxy_system.epoxy_system.name }}

                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="panel-{{ es.epoxy_system.id }}"
                             class="accordion-collapse collapse show">
                            <!-- data-bs-parent="#accordion-a" -->

                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                {% for r in es.responses %}
                                    {{ r.form.csrf_token }}
                                    <b>{{ r.epoxy_system_question.question }}</b>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            {{ render_field(r.form.value) }}

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            {{ render_field(r.form.actual_value) }}

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {{ render_field(r.form.comments) }}

                                    <br>

                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                {% endfor %}

                <!-- </div> -->
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>

        {{ generate_button_form(label='Save and Continue Editing',form='form') }}
        {{ generate_detail_button_form(label='Save and Return to Details', form='form', redirect_url=request.referrer) }}
        {{ generate_button_link(label='Cancel', href=request.referrer) }}
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

buttons.html

```
{% from 'bootstrap5/utils.html' import render_icon %}

{% macro generate_button_form(label='Submit', form='form', class='btn  btn-primary', type='submit') %}
    <button form="{{form}}" class="{{class}}" type="{{type}}">{{label}}</button>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro generate_detail_button_form(label='Submit', form='form', redirect_url='#', class='btn btn-primary', type='submit') %}
    <button form="{{form}}" class="{{class}}" type="{{type}}" onclick="location.href='{{redirect_url}}';">{{label}}</button>
{% endmacro %}


{% macro generate_button_link(label, href='#', icon=None, class='', dropdowns=[], side_dropdown=False) %}

    {% if dropdowns %}

        {% if side_dropdown %}
            <div class="btn-group">

            <a class="btn  {{ class }}" type="button" href="{{ href }}">
                {% if icon %}{{ render_icon(icon) }}{% endif %}{{ label }}</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn  dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split {{ class }}"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
        {% else %}
            <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle {{ class }}" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                {% if icon %}{{ render_icon(icon) }}{% endif %}{{ label }}
            </button>
        {% endif %}

    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        {% for d in dropdowns %}
            {% if d.divider %}
                <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item {{ d.class }}" href="{{ d.href }}">
                    {% if d.icon %}{{ render_icon(d.icon) }}{% endif %}{{ d.label }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% if side_dropdown %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% else %}
        <a class="btn  {{ class }}" type="button" href="{{ href }}">
            {% if icon %}{{ render_icon(icon) }}{% endif %}{{ label }}</a>
    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

As you can see i have two buttons save and continue editing and save and return to detail i want when i click on save and return detail my page will red direct to detail page which link is becomes
Save and Continue Editing button link: http://127.0.0.1:5000/sales/requests/BG-3041-8775-2746/edit/responses
Save and Return to Details button link i want to redirect: http://127.0.0.1:5000/sales/requests/BG-3041-8775-2746/

But it is performing the same functionality on both buttons right now